# ValueError when using sklearn pipeline: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, random-forest

Hi I'm using sklearn pipeline to implement tfidf vectorisation and random forrest. Conducting hyperparameter tuning with BayesSearch with khold cross verification testing.

The first few rounds of the cross verification looks find, but then I got an error on `clf_search.fit(X, y)`

`ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs`. There is no infs or NaNs values in my dataset.

This is my code

```
# pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
      ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,3), norm=None))
    , ("clf", RandomForestClassifier())
])

# parameters
n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 200, stop = 2000, num = 10)]
max_features = ['auto', 'log2']
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 100, num = 11)]
max_depth.append(None)
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10]
min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 4]
bootstrap = [True, False]

# Create the random grid
random_grid = {'clf__n_estimators': n_estimators
              , 'clf__max_features': max_features
              , 'clf__max_depth': max_depth
              , 'clf__min_samples_split': min_samples_split
              , 'clf__min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf
              , 'clf__bootstrap': bootstrap}


# Search
clf_search = BayesSearchCV(pipeline
                                , search_spaces = random_grid
                                , n_iter = 100
                                , cv = 5
                                , verbose=2
                                , random_state=42
                                , n_jobs = -1)
clf_search.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `print(np.sum(np.isnan(X)))` the line before `fit` to make sure you have no nans?

Comment: and `print(np.sum(np.isinf(X)))`

Comment: [Reprex] may be helpful

Comment: @Kosaro I added print(np.sum(np.isnan(X))) before clf_search.fit(X, y). The returned value is 0